# R: automatically assigning all colors

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I am working with the R programming language. I have this data:

```
letters = replicate(52, paste(sample(LETTERS, 10, replace=TRUE), collapse=""))
values = rnorm(52, 100, 100)

my_data = data.frame(letters, values)
```

I am trying to plot this data:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(waffle)

 waffle(my_data, size = 0.6, rows = 10)
```

But this gives me the error:

```
! Insufficient values in manual scale. 51 needed but only 8 provided.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Normally, I would have manually provided the colors - but 51 colors are a lot to insert manually. Is there some automatic way that can recognize how many colors are required and then fill them all in?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The data you created do not produce the error you noted that you observed. Furthermore, you create `my_data` but then pass `waffle()` the object `mydata` (no underscore), so the example is not reproducible at face.

Comment: Note also that: (1) you don't want to name the variable `letters` since `letters()` is a base R function and (2) your sampling is creating a `data.frame` with 52 rows and each row has its own `letters` value. While I can think of some cases where it would still be useful, most of the time a waffle chart is not at all useful when there are not repeated values in the vectors.

After the modifications, the call to `waffle` still does not reproduce your error, instead giving as an error  "'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a vector of 53 colors using a palette function such as `scales::hue_pal()(53)` (note I have had to alter the way the input data is used, since your unmodified example data and code simply returns an error)

```r
waffle(setNames(abs(round(my_data$values/10)), 
                my_data$letters), size = 0.6, rows = 10,
       colors = scales::hue_pal()(53)) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

The obvious caveat is that 53 discrete colors is far too many to have in a waffle plot. It is simply unintelligible from a data visualisation point of view. Whatever you are trying to demonstrate, there will certainly be a better way to do it than a waffle chart with 53 discrete colors.